# "Paired data" / "repeated measures" in 2x2 experiment

Tags: repeated-measures, paired-data

I have test subjects answering questions, the data will be quantitative. The questions can be divided to four categories by two factors that have two levels. For each question a factor A, B, A and B or none are "active". So each subject answers one of these four questions.

I am interested in how the factors A and B affect the answer.

So, this is resembles 2x2 factorial experiment, BUT the data are "paired", in the sense that each subject has answered all of the four questions.

Do you have suggestions for statistical tests I can use? Do you know how situations like this has been dealt with before?

EDIT: I found out that "repeated measures design" might be relevant.

Comment: Can you clarify your situation a bit.  I do not understand your sentence, "For each question a factor A, B, A and B or none are "active"."

Comment: You mentioned that the response was quantitative but did not say that it was numeric on a scale from 0-100. I was thinking that there would be a small number of possible responses and that they could be counted with cell frequencies. Now that you clarify it, it looks like something more like a generalization of a paired test (t, sign, signed rank) is what is needed. – Michael Chernick just now edit You mentioned that the response was quantitative but did not say that it was numeric on a scale from 0-100.

Comment: I was thinking that there would be a small number of possible responses and that they could be counted with cell frequencies. Now that you clarify it, it looks like something more like a generalization of a paired test (t, sign, signed rank) is what is needed.